# Error starting kafka server in Windows 10

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing issue when starting Kafka server in my local machine (Windows 10) using command bin\windows\kafka-server-start \config\server.properties. I am getting error below. I already have zookeeper server running.

```
[2018-12-26 12:03:14,124] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController 
 MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
 [2018-12-26 12:03:14,155] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception 
 (kafka.Kafka$)
 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \config\server.properties
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:560)
        at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:42)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:58)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Comment: Voting to close as typo. You could verify the same error with `dir \config` because the leading slash is not a valid path in Windows

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using kafka 2.12-2.1.1 version.
For me it worked when I initialize the kafka server with the following input:

```
kafka-server-start.bat \Tools\kafka_2.12-2.1.1\config\server.properties
```

Obs: Command source from the kafka_2.12-2.1.1\bin\windows
Obs2: I created the Tools folder inside C: to put the kafka and zookeeper files inside.

Answer (score 3):

Running **kafka-server-start.bat** from within: 
`C:\Apache\kafka_2.12–2.3.1\bin\windows>`

and using a relative path like this:

```
kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties
```

worked for me, for both `kafka_2.12–2.3.1` and `kafka-2.4.0`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running kafka-server-start from kafka home directory, remove "\" before config. It should do the magic.

```
bin\windows\kafka-server-start config\server.properties
```

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Thanks ..yes the extra \ was the problem.  I was able to start the server.

Answer (score 1):

**For those who have added kafka binary's path to window's environment PATH variable and still stuck** : Passing relative path of server.properties (like **..\..\config\server.properties**) with respect to binary location (as added in PATH) will not work. You will have to pass absolute path for server.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to find the server.properties file in the same folder.
Provide the absolute path as below and it runs successfully.

kafka-server-start.bat C:\DEVTools\kafka_2.12-2.3.1\config\server.properties